# Internet Recovery failed with -2002U code

Tags: macos, install, recovery, internet

I have a MacBook Pro 2012 that when I try to recover from the internet using WiFi, I always get the error to call Apple Support with the code -2002U. I tried several times to solve this problem without any luck. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

After several attempts using WiFi, I tried to hook up the MacBook Pro 2012 using an Ethernet cable directly to the router. This time it was able to connect to the Apple servers and the Internet Recovery worked.